# Linker errors for iOS 9 and above after disabling bitcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, openssl

I have integrated **openssl** library using cocoa pods in my project. It is working fine in xcode 7.1, simulator 7.0 and above.
But when I am trying to install in physical iOS device, getting the below mentioned issue:

> You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting
>   ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable
>   bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

After setting up the enable bitocde to NO, I can able to run the project in iOS 7/8 device.

But while I am trying to run my application in  iOS 9 or later version device, I am getting multiple errors from the dependency I have added to my project.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried manually adding that lib into your project?

Comment: Did you update al our libraries to bitcode enabled once? Just like in stated in the error message.

Comment: @Tj3n i have added the lib file manually but i got the library path error thats why i use pods .

Comment: @rckoenes yes i did that also ,getting the same issue

Comment: Please post the text of the linker error; and not a picture of it. The next person to have the problem will not find this question because it lacks the critical text. Do so by adding it to the question by clicking *Edit*, and don't post it as a comment. You can find the *Edit* link in the bottom left hand corner of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally get something fixed on my error

When a application uses openssl library. Developer need to set the enable bitcode mode as multiple values for both target and project .

**1.While Debugging the application**

While debugging the enable bitcode for Debug should be **NO** and Release should be **YES** .

**2.While Releasing the application**

In this case the Enable bitcode for debug should be **YES** and Release mode should be **NO**.

I followed these above steps so that i could able to debug the application and pushed to Appstore successfully with out getting any error.

Hope this answer will help others.

Answer (score 2):

You have to either check `copy files if needed` when you drag it or else you have to add the path into your `library search path` in build setting if you want manually adding the lib, for the pod one, my best guess is that you missing some dependency library like c, c++, z (maybe it run in c++) in your project or the lib's podspec doesnt included, so best is try to manually adding it

Comment: i have some issue with adding the lib manually,so i need to added the openssl files using pods